# How to export your class adding export default class FlatListDemo extends Component

Tags: react-native

I can't understand gow to modify the code by the advice from my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65323844/how-to-call-class-in-function-on-react-native). Can someone send a listing of the class added in a function please?

Comment: If you want your questions answered, please put some more effort in organizing the question to help other people understand it.

Comment: @cltsang I sent a link for the last question